# Is it possible to simplify this expression in Mathematica?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Let us consider an expression  $$\frac{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{2-x^2}+x} \sqrt[6]{1-x \sqrt{2-x^2}}}{\sqrt[3]{1-x^2}}.$$

Its plot

```
Plot[Surd[x + Sqrt[2 - x^2], 3]*Surd[1 - x*Sqrt[2 - x^2], 6]/Surd[1 - x^2, 3], {x, -Sqrt[2], Sqrt[2]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

clearly shows this is `Piecewise[{{2^(1/6),x>=-Sqrt[2]&&x<-1||x>-1&&x<1},{-2^(1/6),x>1&&x<=Sqrt[2]}}]`.

However, my attempts of its simplification

```
FullSimplify[Surd[x + Sqrt[2 - x^2], 3]*Surd[1 - x*Sqrt[2 - x^2], 6]/Surd[1 - x^2, 3], Assumptions -> x > 1]
```

and

```
FullSimplify[Surd[x + Sqrt[2 - x^2], 3]* Surd[1 - x*Sqrt[2 - x^2], 6]/Surd[1 - x^2, 3],Assumptions ->( x >= -Sqrt[2] && x < -1)||(x>-1&&x<1)]
```

fail.

Knowing the result by substitution `x==0` and `x==Sqrt[2]`, the simplification can be established by

```
Reduce[Surd[x + Sqrt[2 - x^2], 3]*Surd[1 - x*Sqrt[2 - x^2], 6]/Surd[1 - x^2, 3] == 2^(1/6), x, Reals]
```

> `-Sqrt[2] <= x < -1 || -1 < x < 1`

and

```
Reduce[Surd[x + Sqrt[2 - x^2], 3]*Surd[1 - x*Sqrt[2 - x^2], 6]/ Surd[1 - x^2, 3] == -2^(1/6), x, Reals]
```

> `1 < x <= Sqrt[2]`

Is there another way to simplify it  in Mathematica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed, `Reduce` is more suitable in this case. But one does not need to know the answer in advance. Can be done as follows.

Define an expression to simplify

```
f = Surd[x + Sqrt[2 - x^2], 3] Surd[1 - x Sqrt[2 - x^2], 6]/Surd[1 - x^2, 3]
```

Perform simplification

```
FullSimplify[Reduce[y == f && #, x, Reals] & /@ FunctionDomain[f, x]]
```

$$\left(y+\sqrt[6]{2}=0\land 1<x\leq \sqrt{2}\right)\lor \left(y=\sqrt[6]{2}\land \left(-1<x<1\lor -\sqrt{2}\leq x<-1\right)\right)$$

Comment: +1. This can be simplified; `FullSimplify[Reduce[y == f, x, Reals]]` results in `(2^(1/6) + y == 0 && 
   1 < x <= Sqrt[2]) || (y == 2^(
    1/6) && (-Sqrt[2] <= x < -1 || -1 < x < 1))`.

Comment: @user64494 Interesting, I tried it in MA11, but it take too long. I was not patient enough, and therefore, I divided `FunctionDomain` into subdomains and applied  `Reduce` separately.

Comment: You may try it in the Wolfram Cloud. I am on 12.3.1.

Comment: So does `Reduce[y == f, x, Reals] // ToRadicals` in 12.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer to the question. We start from

```
FunctionDomain[Surd[x+Sqrt[2-x^2],3]*Surd[1 - x*Sqrt[2 - x^2], 6]/Surd[1 - x^2, 3],x,Reals]
```

> `-Sqrt[2] <= x < -1 || -1 < x < 1 || 1 < x <= Sqrt[2]`

Therefore, the domain consists of three intervals. On every one of these intervals the function under consideration is constant. This follows from

```
FullSimplify[D[Surd[x + Sqrt[2 - x^2], 3]*Surd[1 - x*Sqrt[2 - x^2], 6]/Surd[1 - x^2, 3], x]]
```

> `Piecewise[{{0, x*Sqrt[2 - x^2] <= 1}}, Indeterminate]`

and

```
Reduce[x Sqrt[2 - x^2] <= 1, x, Reals]
```

> `-Sqrt[2] <= x <= Sqrt[2]`

and the mean value theorem. The values of these constants can be found by substitutions `x==-Sqrt[2]` and `x==0` and `x==Sqrt[2]`.

Addition. Another approach consists in

```
Resolve[ ForAll[x, x > 1 && x <= Sqrt[2], f == c], Reals]//ToRadicals
```

> `c == -2^(1/6)`

```
  Resolve[ ForAll[x, x < -1 && x >= -Sqrt[2], f == c], Reals]//ToRadicals
```

> `c == 2^(1/6)`